# Naive Bayes Python Probabilidad error

Tags: python

Tengo una pregunta, y es que tengo 2 dataset, uno es AdultTest y otro AdultData.

En esos dataset tiene muchas filas de este tipo:

```
39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Female , 2174, 0, 40, United-States, >50K
```

y querría calcular la probabilidad de que Un "Female" tenga más de >50K, para ello hice lo siguiente:

```
    #Lee AdultData.csv y lo pone como Integer, así puede calcular el naiveBAyes
    data1= np.genfromtxt('AdultData.csv',delimiter=',', dtype='int',skip_footer=1)
datatest=np.genfromtxt('adultTest.csv',delimiter=',', dtype='int',skip_footer=1)

    #Borra la ultima columna, porque esa es el target
    data_new=np.delete(data2, 14, 1)
dataTest_new=np.delete(datatest, 14, 1)
    Class =[row[14] for row in data2]
    from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
    clf= BernoulliNB()
    clf.fit(data_new, Class)
    print(clf.predict_proba(data_new))
# print(clf.predict_proba(dataTest_new))
```

y como resultado de la predicción de probabilidad me da siempre :

[1. 0.]

no entiendo por qué, aunque ponga el de AdultTest, sale los mismos resultados, a pesar de que tiene otros datos, porque no obtengo otros resultados? además que quiere decir las 2 columnas?

alguien me podría ayudar?

Un saludo y gracias de antemano!

Comment: sabes cuales son sus parametros del algoritmo bayes?

Comment: debería de ser todas las columnas menos ">50K" no?

Comment: esos son datos de training para la fase de entrenamiento de tu conjunto de datos

Comment: si, eso son. El objetivo es entrenar un ranker que ponga las probabilidades de que una mujer tenga >50K

Comment: cual es el rol de skip_footer? y que significa 1?

Comment: en el csv hay una linea que esta mal echa, entonces no la tomo encuenta para crear la matriz

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82424/discussion-between-x-rw-and-tomaatetip).

Comment: lei un poco, este algoritmo necesita D = {(x1,y1), … (xn,yn)}, en que parte de tu codigo usas el parametro D?

Comment: pero D es el data_new, no? 

PD. te he escrito en el chat

Comment: esto es lo que quiero hacer  está en la página 3:
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4909197/

Comment: @x-rw una pregunta, sabes cual la diferencia entre una matriz asi: [ 2 4 5] y [ 2,4,5]?

por cierto, has conseguido algo?